# WP-CLI.phar "could not open input file"

Tags: php, windows, wordpress, command-line, wp-cli

I am trying to install `wp-cli` on windows using cygwin on windows 10. I used the directions on the official site: http://wp-cli.org/docs/installing/ using the 'installing on windows' instructions, not through composer. PHP is installed via XAMPP and was added to the PATH. `php --info` returns

```
PHP Version => 5.6.3.
```

I created a `wp-cli` folder in `c:` drive and added `wp-cli.phar` and `wp.bat`. `wp.bat --info` returns:

```
PHP binary:             C:\xampp\php\php.exe
PHP version:            5.6.3
php.ini used:           C:\xampp\php\php.ini
WP-CLI root dir:        phar://wp-cli.phar
WP-CLI packages dir:    C:\cygwin64\home\A57/.wp-cli/packages/
WP-CLI global config:
WP-CLI project config:
WP-CLI version: 0.23.0
```

But when I type `$ wp-cli.phar --info` it returns:

```
Could not open input file: /cygdrive/c/wp-cli/wp-cli.phar
```

Please help

Answer (score 2):

I've just achieved this! (After much pain, I might add ...)

My problem was that the .bat file I had created had another hidden extension, so that the file was actually registering by the system as a text file, instead of a `Windows Batch File`.

By deleting the file and starting again in a text editor, pasting these commands in:

`@ECHO OFF
php "c:/wp-cli/wp-cli.phar" %*`

Then saving the file as a .bat and MAKING SURE YOU SELECT `ALL FILES (*)`  as the file type, it recognised it, and I am now able to run wp-cli in the command line.

Comment: Ah, when I looked at this command in a little more detail, you might want to run this command: `php wp-cli info` - please ensure you have php cli installed too!